# Daily Database backup using Cron Job

Tags: mysql, linux, cron, crontrigger

Hi i want to take  database backup  at daily mid night using cron job... and the name of database backup should append with current date... the format of backup file should be mydata_yyyy_mm_dd.sql ...
backup file should be placed in /root directory

Answer (score 22, accepted):

something like

```
0 0 * * * /path/to/mysqldump ... > /path/to/backup/mydata_$( date +"%Y_%m_%d" ).sql
```

should work.

Please read

- man date
- man 5 crontab

Comment: I had to add escaping slashes to the `%`, as `%` is often interpreted by cron as a newline character. E.g., `... /path/to/backup/mydata_$( date +"\%Y_\%m_\%d" )`.

Comment: centos 6.4 is ok. didn't need the escapes

Comment: @wonk0 please guide me regarding this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33057744/send-email-via-cron-job-every-day-with-database-csv-xls-or-xml-file-backup-usi

Answer (score 7):

Create a cron.sh file with this content:

```
 mysqldump -u root -p{PASSWORD} DBNAME 2>> "/filename_`date '+%Y-%m-%d'`.sql"
```

And give the Read permission or full access permission for that cron.sh file.

and add this line into crontab file ($ crontab -e)

```
 0 0 * * *   cron.sh
```

Comment: mysqldump: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) when trying to connect

Comment: Got the same error. Got error: 1045: Access denied for user (using password: NO) when trying to connect