# send email via Cron job every day with database csv / xls or xml file backup using php in linux server

Tags: php, mysql, excel, csv, cron

This is first time i am trying to setup Cron Job. I need your help.
I have get db data into csv/xls file but i don't know how can i set cron job once on daily basis with this file via email along with data.

**Database table with data**

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `student`;
CREATE TABLE `student` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `name` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `major` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=7 ;

-- 
-- Dumping data for table `student`
-- 

INSERT INTO `student` VALUES (1, 'John', 'Computer Science');
INSERT INTO `student` VALUES (2, 'Victor', 'Multimedia');
INSERT INTO `student` VALUES (3, 'Tomy', 'Networking');
INSERT INTO `student` VALUES (4, 'Will', 'Database');
INSERT INTO `student` VALUES (5, 'Jacky', 'Techincal');
```

**data.php**

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>NO.</th>
        <th>NAME</th>
        <th>Major</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
    //connection to mysql
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", ""); //server , username , password
    mysql_select_db("codelution");

    //query get data
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM student ORDER BY id ASC");
    $no = 1;
    while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
        echo '
        <tr>
            <td>'.$no.'</td>
            <td>'.$data['name'].'</td>
            <td>'.$data['major'].'</td>
        </tr>
        ';
        $no++;
    }
    ?>
</table>
```

**export.php**

```
<?php
// The function header by sending raw excel
header("Content-type: application/vnd-ms-excel");

// Defines the name of the export file "codelution-export.xls"
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=codelution-export.xls");

// Add data table
include 'data.php';
?>
```

and finally you need this file **codelution-export.xls**
**[full code](http://codelution.com/development/web/easy-ways-to-export-data-from-mysql-to-excel-with-php/)**

Comment: Not quite sure why you are trying to make the data export a PHP script that runs on the webserver. If you are using a cron it can be a stand along php script. In fact it doesn't even need to be a PHP script. You can just use mysqldump and one of the many command line mail clients available for linux to achieve this more easily and neatly.

Comment: please help me if it is possible without script my requirement is just to send email database data in csv format once a daily. Thanks