# how Can we have a table backup scheduled

Tags: php, symfony, cron

I would like to do a backup of a table from my database every 24 hours.
I use symfony 2.8.9, can any one help me and show me how can i use the cron to have the backup every day.

Thanks.

Comment: The cron has nothing to do with symfony, it's on your server

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Daily Database backup using Cron Job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578533/daily-database-backup-using-cron-job)